# Parsing an arrayList

Tags: android

I am new to android. How do I parse this array list

```
{apptName=Ken O'Reily, apptClientId=1056, apptOption1=Option1: Sun 11/26/2017 01:30 PM}
```

(sent from another activity)?

Comment: What is it? How do you get it? Any code?

Comment: Also, this looks like a JSON, but is incorrect! It does not follow the structure. Please provide more info!

Comment: So you want to parse the hash into an array? In that case you can use something like this: ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>(hw.values());

Comment: @jorjSB It might be a HashMap, Map, or even WeakHashmap, but not JSON. JSON is usually structured like this: {"bar": "foo", "stack" : "overflow"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an arraylist, its a Map. You can pass it to second activity by doing this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("data" yourData);
startActivity(i);
```

Then get the data from SecondActivity by doing this...

```
        HashMap<String, Object> data = (HashMap)getIntent().getSerializable("data");
    String apptName =data.get("apptName").toString();
Log.v("APPT NAME: ", apptName)
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Thanks DevMike. It helps.